# How to invoke a controller from URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I've an application in my localhost (localhost/supplies/) and the default controller have specified in routes.php file.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "start";
```

The problem is when i want load or execute a controller when the URL is "localhost/supplies/admin/" or "localhost/supplies/admin".

I did test with

```
$route['admin'] = "controllers/admin";
```

But it doesn't works.

Comment: Did you read the manual? Routing (and the rest) is pretty well documented

Answer (score 0):

If your application root is in `localhost/supplies` there is no reason to route that.

URL `localhost/supplies/admin` will call the `admin` controller without need for any routing.

(Works if you omitted index.php from the URL.)

Your suggested routing would call the *method* `admin` in the *controller* named `controller`

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$route['admin'] = "admin/yourcontrollerName";
```